# Benefit of binding functions to names in local scopes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I read something a day or so ago, couldn't remember where, and the author of the post noted that it is better to bind function calls to a name in local space rather than making the `.` access call.

For example:

```
def foo():
    a = math.cos
    b = math.sin
    x = a(1) * b(0)
```

vs

```
def foo():
    x = math.cos(1) * math.sin(0)
```

Now this was in the context of performance and if those calls were made more than once, but it got me wondering why does it perform better at all and when should it be used like such? Doesn't doing this just begin to clutter up the namespace?

Comment: In this specific case, there won't be a performance benefit. But if you call a method multiple time, e.g. in a loop, then the relatively high costs of method resolution in Python can have measurable effects on performance. Note, not only does resolving the attribute, `x.some_attr` cost a lot, but if it turns out to be a function, then a bound-method object is recreated every time.

Comment: I would only worry about this if you're working on something very performance sensitive. Be sure to choose good names.  If you're doing this to imports, then you should probably have just imported the name on it's own from the other module `from math import sin, cos`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Assume `x` is a class and `x.some_method` gets called a lot. Is there a way to improve the performance?

Comment: This "trick" is more stylistic than performant.  I sometimes use it where I've got lines that are very long because they contain calls to one or more lengthy function names, and I would like to shorted the line by breaking it up without abbreviating the function names.  It's just a style thing, though.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Indeed I am, DBSCAN along a KDTree of ECEF points.

Comment: @BowlingHawk95 That sounds like the inverse of the two prior posts...?

Comment: @pstatix if you mean `x` is some *instance of a class*, then yeah, do `some_method = x.some_method` and then use `some_method` in place of `x.some_method`

Comment: @pstatix How? My point was not to worry about the performance difference between the implementations.  The above posts are correct, but 999 times out of 1000, the performance impact of one pointer assignment is not going to be noticeable.  So hence my suggestion to think of this as more of a stylistic difference than performance.  If your question really has to do with a performance-critical system (to which I'd ask why you're writing it in python), then see above posts.

Comment: @BowlingHawk95 _"...(to which I'd ask why you're writing it in python)..."_ I am using the tools I have available.

Comment: @BowlingHawk95 it's not a simple pointer assignment at all. Check [this article](https://medium.com/stepping-through-the-cpython-interpreter/how-does-attribute-access-work-d19371898fee) that goes through what normal attribute access does in Python. Indeed, this is why `__slots__` was added, to make this much more performant. There is also the creation of an entire new object each time (the bound method object). It isn't trivial.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Doesn't just importing `from math import sin, cos` still have the overhead global lookup as `math.sin` and `math.cos`?

Comment: I don't believe so.  As I understand it, the namespace is a mapping of names to objects.  So in your original example, you have a name `math` that points to the `module` object representing the `math` module `{"math": <module math>}`.  You then basically do `getattr(math, 'sin')` to resolve `math.sin`.  In contrast, when you `from math import sin`, you create the mapping `{"sin": <function sin>}`, so when you dereference `sin` you skip that `getattr` step.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh there is still overhead from the global lookup, which is a dictionary lookup, versus a local variable lookup, which is optimized to a symbol-table lookup. This one is even more minor than the method-resolution and bound-method object creation

Answer (score 2):

I did some profiling to get a sense of what the actual difference between these is.  You can [find the REPL here](https://repl.it/@Haugh/AmazingFewRuby)
from timeit import timeit

```
import math
from math import sin

x = 10_000_000


def from_import():
    for _ in range(x):
        sin(100)


def import_module():
    for _ in range(x):
        math.sin(100)


def local_var():
    s = math.sin
    for _ in range(x):
        s(100)


def local_import():
    from math import sin
    for _ in range(x):
        sin(100)


funcs = (from_import, import_module, local_var, local_import)

for func in funcs:
    print("{:<15} {}".format(
        func.__name__, timeit(
            func.__name__ + '()', number=1, globals=globals())))
```

The results:

```
from_import     4.354339323996101
import_module   5.608195230990532
local_var       3.982630196987884
local_import    3.9956486110022524
```

I was surprised that the local names were that much more performant over the global names.  Both vastly outperform additional attribute lookups.

Comment: Neat little test, thanks for that. Now the question slightly turns to _"When should one do this?"_. Surely a trade-off like this isn't worth assigning method calls to a local variable in every single function scope?? For the class instance method calls I can see why since it has a ton of overhead, but for this, seems like more lines of code.